# How to call default method from interface with TestNG tests and Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, java-8, testng, default-method

I want to know if it is possible to use default methods from interface with  TestNG `@BeforeMethod` annotation?

Here is sample, which I tried:

```
@Listeners(TestListener.class)
public interface ITestBase {
    String baseUrl = Config.getProperty(Config.TEST_HOST);
    String driverName = Config.getProperty(Config.BROWSER);
    DriversEnum driverInstance = DriversEnum.valueOf(driverName.toUpperCase());

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    default public void start() {
        try {
            driver.init();
            DriverUnit.preconfigureDriver(Driver.driver.get());
            driver.get().manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.get().get(baseUrl);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            Logger.logEnvironment("QT application is not available");
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    default public void end() {
        if (driver.get() != null) {
            try {
                driver.get().quit();
            } catch (UnreachableBrowserException e) {
                Logger.logDebug("UnreachableBrowser on close");
            } finally {
                driver.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run typical TestNG test method, like:

```
public class AppUiDemo implements ITestBase {
    @Test(enabled = true)
    public void checkWebDriverCreation() {
      ...
    }
```

`start()` and `end()` methods aren't called. Driver instance isn't created for test execution.

Is it possible to make something like it with `default` method and TestNG methods?

If I change the interface to a regular class, before and after methods are called (driver instance is created fine):

```
public class TestBase {
    protected final String baseUrl = Config.getProperty(Config.TEST_HOST);
    protected final String driverName = Config.getProperty(Config.BROWSER);
    protected final DriversEnum driverInstance = DriversEnum.valueOf(driverName.toUpperCase());

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void start() {
    ....
```

The problem is that my test class is already extending another class:

```
public class MainTest extends ExecutionContext
```

Thus I can't extend `TestBase`.

***Is it possible to use interface with any implementation for execution code before and after test methods?***

Comment: I don't follow.  I see some `static` methods in your interface, but not default methods.  I also see non-`static`, non-`final` fields in your interface, so what gives?  By "It doesn't work" do you mean "it doesn't compile"?  Because no, it wouldn't.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I fixed typo. I also tried static methods as well.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are wrong. I do. Also, `String baseUrl` is by default `public static final`. And type something like it isn't mandatory. To my mind, it is redundant and makes readability much more difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but the version of TestNG that allow using interface methods in tests is not released yet. You need to download it from [this](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots) repository.

If you use ***Maven*** you can specify additional repository in your `pom.xml`:

```
<repository>
    <id>testng</id>
    <name>testng</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
</repository>
```

And then add TestNG dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

**Example:**

```
package test;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DummyTest implements ITest {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeTest() {
        System.out.println("before from class");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("I am test1");
    }
}
```

and **ITest** interface

```
package test;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

public interface ITest {

    @BeforeMethod
    default void beforeDefaultInterface() {
        System.out.println("before from default interface method");
    }
    @BeforeMethod
    static void beforeStaticInterface() {
        System.out.println("before from static interface method");
    }
}
```

The output of the test above will be:

```
    before from default interface method
    before from static interface method
    before from class
    I am test1
```

Comment: excellent! I was wondering if this is still in progress on the TestNG side

Comment: @Anton Could give more information how to take from a repository which you shared? I couldn't find `testng` there.

Comment: Updated my answer with example for maven. The exact link where jar file can be found is https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/testng/testng/6.11.1-SNAPSHOT/

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible with TestNg version '6.14.2'**

Alternative repo, no longer required.
I have not tried other versions.